# Asus zenfone 5 USB device not recognised by windows 8.1

Tags: android

I have zenfone 5 (A501CG) with Kitkat 4.4.2. When I connects mobile to my laptop it shows popup saying that "**USB device not recognized**. the previously connected device is malfunctioned".
To solve this problem, i have did following:

- From **control panel->hardware and sounds->device manager**. there is one device named **

> **Unknown USB Device(Device descriptor request failed**

Here i have updated device driver it says that "**device driver is up-to-date**". But problem is still there.
Can anybody please help me?

Comment: It's not related to programming. You might ask this question on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

In your smartphone.

Go in Settings > Storage > Click on USB icon (Near of the clock) > Mark Media Device (MTP).

... Waiting a Moment ... and be happy.